# Where to find this ReactiveUI.Routing?

Tags: nuget, reactiveui

I got a sample code that I couldn't get to compile. It is complaining about a missing Reference to ReactiveUI.Routing.dll

The piece of code that is using it is some Xaml code using RoutedViewHost element.

I looked up in Nuget for ReactiveUI-Routing. No help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RoutedViewHost is now in ReactiveUI.Xaml.dll, which is in the ReactiveUI-Platforms NuGet package. Since you haven't specified which major version of RxUI you're using, it's more difficult to help.

In ReactiveUI 4.x and below, this is in an assembly called ReactiveUI.Routing.dll, which is in the ReactiveUI-Xaml NuGet package.

Comment: I've been out of touch with Rx stuff, any good read on Routing ? What does it do ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a look in the latest source code and couldn't find a project of that name or any direct members of the namespace ReactiveUI.Routing. There were some references in the test projects though. I wonder if they re-factored its members into the main dll?

Perhaps try pulling the source from https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI and compiling yourself?

Comment: I found it. Its part of ReactiveUI.Xaml project. Earlier it was part of ReactiveUI. Don't know who is doing that but every next version they try to make developer's life difficult.